# Unable to get upload project from bitbucket

Tags: php, bitbucket, checkin

I am new in bitbucket.I want to upload project from Linux to bitbucket.successfully I have created a bitbucket account and did the following

1)create a repository name 'testadmin'
2)Using command line `cd /var/www/myname/myprojectname`

```
git init
git remote add origin https://username@bitbucket.org/user/testadmin.git
git pull origin master
```

then I get

```
Password for 'https://user@bitbucket.org': 
From https://bitbucket.org/user/testadmin
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
 README.md | 29 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 29 insertions(+)
```

But I didn't get my project from bitbucket.Please help me

Comment: Have you added code on Bitbucket's repository?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay :now there is one file README.md

Comment: So if there is not project code in repository then how can you get your project from there? When you pulled, you would have got readme.md file from there. Didn't you?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay : I want to upload project from my linux machine to bitbucket.so i did the following commands..I am new in bit bucket please correct me i had make anything wrong

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks dear ..thankyew very much.it's working now..

Comment: you got your project up on the repo?

Answer (score 0):

ok, then
I would advice you to keep your project folder in `www` directly. Like if your project folder name is project_1 then it should be at `var/www/html/project_1`

then open terminal and reach to the folder `project_1` 
`cd /var/www/html/project_1` and then as you have already initiated git and added remote origin so you just need to push your code to repo.
To do so, follow these steps:

1) You need to add all the files to a commit bucket to upload on repo. For that,

```
git add -A (it will add all the files of the folder project_1)
```

2) Commit files with a message to track your uploaded work

```
git commit -m "First time uploading project 1"  // The commit message will be for your reference.
```

3) Push the commited code now:

```
`git push origin master`  // this command will push the code to master branch which is the default branch in a repo. You can create any branches on Bitbucket and add their name after origin to push to that particular branch.
```

After these 3 commands, check your repo. You should see your project up there.

Comment if you need further help.